# Application Customizer scope

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

Application Customizer extensions are supported with Site, Web, and List scopes. You can control the scope by deciding where or how the Application Customizer is registered in your SharePoint tenant.

My Question:

How can I restrict the scope to list? What is the deployment check list when it is deployed to a list?

Answer (score 0):

It should just be like other User Custom Actions in SharePoint. You could define it in the XML:

```
<CustomAction 
        Title="ATitle"
        RegistrationId="101"
        RegistrationType="List"
        Location="ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar"
        ClientSideComponentId="659c5d7c-2cad-46bf-b05d-c6fdadcd47a1"
        ClientSideComponentProperties="{}">
</CustomAction>
```

With powershell:

```
Add-PnPCustomAction -Name "AName" -Title "ATitle" -Location "ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar" -ClientSideComponentId "659c5d7c-2cad-46bf-b05d-c6fdadcd47a1" -RegistrationId 101 -ClientSideComponentProperties "" -RegistrationType List
```